# kernel ignores append init=/bin/bash

Tags: boot, init, init-script, kernel-parameters

```
 qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2G -accel kvm -kernel kernel6.1 -append "init=/bin/bash" -initrd myinitrd.gz
```

Supposed to run bash as init, but kernel still prints:

```
[    1.400577] Run /init as init process
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's because of CONFIG_CMDLINE_FORCE=y being defined on the kernel. Maybe rebuild it with CONFIG_CMDLINE_FORCE=n?

> Set this to have arguments from the default kernel command string
> override those passed by the boot loader. [1]

[1] https://www.kernelconfig.io/config_cmdline_force